# Dynamic script tag using server active notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using server and client in same machine by ajax connectivity it shows the inactive state of server. On using dynamic script tag it doesn't reflect the inactivness of server. How could this be resolved?

we have included these functions in a .js file.

```
function JSONscriptRequest(fullUrl) {

    this.fullUrl = fullUrl; 
    this.noCacheIE = '&noCacheIE=' + (new Date()).getTime();

    this.headLoc = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);

    this.scriptId = 'JscriptId' + JSONscriptRequest.scriptCounter++;
}

JSONscriptRequest.scriptCounter = 1;

JSONscriptRequest.prototype.buildScriptTag = function () {


    this.scriptObj = document.createElement("script");


    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("charset", "utf-8");
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("src", this.fullUrl + this.noCacheIE);
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("id", this.scriptId);
}


JSONscriptRequest.prototype.removeScriptTag = function () {

    this.headLoc.removeChild(this.scriptObj); 
}


JSONscriptRequest.prototype.addScriptTag = function () {

    this.headLoc.appendChild(this.scriptObj);
}
```

and used the following code in jsp page

```
// The web service call

var req  = <<<url of the service which resides in different server>>>&callback=<callback function>; 

// Create a new request object

bObj = new JSONscriptRequest(req); 

// Build the dynamic script tag

bObj.buildScriptTag(); 

// Add the script tag to the page

bObj.addScriptTag();
```

Comment: Do you have some code we can take a look at? It's easier for us to help you if you provide a coded example :) www.jsfiddle.net is a great resource for this.

Comment: what is ` it doesn't reflect the inactivness of server`  in your therms ? As i see that object create script tag with given src